# Spark unzip from S3

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Spark (pyspark) to read in data and have ran into a snag as some of my data is now in .gz format.

```
%pyspark
data = sc.textFile("s3://mybucket.file.gz")
data.first()


    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-5205743886772607083.py", line 267, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-5205743886772607083.py", line 260, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1041, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1032, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 906, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 809, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 31.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 31.0 (TID 270, ip-172-16-238-231.us-west-1.compute.internal, executor 17): java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.inflateBytesDirect(Native Method)
```

Any thoughts on how to read this in and uncompress?

Comment: See some documentation here: https://github.com/bernhard-42/spark-unzip#2-gzip-compressed-data

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, all I had to do is remove the "gz" off the end and it worked.